# Git returning null on hudson

Tags: java, git, continuous-integration, hudson, fetch

I am working on a project using git with hudson to build some tests. I have done all the hudson configurations (at least  think I did) and I downloaded git for windows. The repository is located on our office linux machine. When I build the tests here is the error I'm getting:

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\username\.hudson\jobs\GitTest\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@35e5abf2
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:test2 / C:\Users\username\git\test2 - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@35e5abf2
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from user@gitrepo:/var/gitrepo/test
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch -t user@gitrepo:/var/gitrepo/test +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
null
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:931)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:889)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:791)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:773)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:889)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:668)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1515)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:521)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:428)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:81)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
```

For some reason the fetch command returns null. When I try the command on command line, it just hangs with no output until I have to kill it. I've been researching this for a while now but could not find any answer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the command doesn't work on the command line, it sure isn't going to work in hudson. Can you use git at all from the command line? Is it a bad Git installation/configuration, or just that one command?

Comment: I can use git from the command line, I mean I've successfully added a github repository and was able to push and pull stuff. When I try running that one command, it just hangs

Comment: does it hang at the command line, or just in hudson?

Comment: It hangs at the command line also

Comment: Can you please update your question with the exact commands you are running from the command line and the output that it produces? It will be much easier to diagnose the issue then. As @GreyBeardedGeek says, Hudson is probably just a red herring in this case.

Comment: @ben.snape so when I run the following command: "git fetch -t user@gitrepo:/var/gitrepo/test +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master", there is no output at all. It just hangs. Even trying to kill it doesn't work, I have to close the whole command prompt window for it to stop. Running the command"git remote -v" gives : "user@gitrepo:/var/gitrepo/test"

Comment: if you are using SSH, make sure your keys are all configured between github and your jenkins instance

Comment: Is not "user@gitrepo:/var/gitrepo/test" a strange name for a remote?  Maybe that does not work on msysgit due to some /\\ magic?

Comment: Is `gitrepo` the name of the machine containing the git repository you are trying to clone / fetch from?

Comment: No gitrepo is not the name of the machine. I just didn't want to put it out there..the repo is on one of our linux machines...

Answer (score 1):

I had something like this happened, it turned out it was the fingerprint (if your git is using RSA verification) that wasn't automatically accepted the first time we queried the repo>.

I solved it by doing a manual query on the repo as the hudson user:

```
git ls-remote -h git@yourepo.git HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

i am able to solve this problem by adding windows Environment Variable.

```
Name: HOME
Value: $USERPROFILE
```

for more info go to below URL,
http://element34.ca/blog/jenkins-remote-windows-nodes-and-private-github-repos